# Can combining C3, C4 and CAM plants in a greenhouse/vertical farm increase the efficiency of plant production?

Tags: plant-physiology, food, photosynthesis

I am reading a little about different types of photosynthetic systems in plants because I want to learn something about plant production in greenhouses/vertical farms (I have no experience in this field).

Can combining C3, C4 and CAM plants in a certain way have positive effects on its production value? So for example C3 and CAM plants are planted in the same area close to each other and they have in some way a positive effect on each other because they use different methods for assimilating energy and thus one can bring down the energy use in the greenhouse/vertical farm.

This is an interesting article. 
https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/photosynthesis-in-plants/photorespiration--c3-c4-cam-plants/a/c3-c4-and-cam-plants-agriculture

It explains the different aspects of the different plants very well. Maybe the best answer to my question is a simple: NO, because all 3 types of plants grow naturally in different environments, but I can imagine a system were energy that is gained from their photosynthesis at different times of the day can be shared among the plants and thus an increased energy efficiency can be reached. Maybe someone can